Product of all binomial coefficients
I was writing a research paper in Computer Science.
I had to provide an upper bound for the number of steps of the algorithm I had found with my colleagues; the nature of the algorithm is totally irrelevant.
I considered the worst case scenario of my algorithm, and I started calculating the number of steps. I ended up with a big mess of binomial coefficients, but carefully, step after step, everything simplified down to just the following product:
$$ \prod _{j = 0}^N {}\binom{N}{j}.$$
Initially, I assumed there was no better form for this product. In fact, there are several identities about binomial coefficients, but they all involve sums and not products.
Nonetheless, I tried out of curiosity to read the Wikipedia page about Binomial coefficients.
To my greatest surprise, there was a section exactly about the formula I sought. Namely, Wikipedia claims the following identity is true:
$$ \prod _{j = 0}^N {}\binom{N}{j} = \prod_{k = 1}^N k^{2k - N -1}.$$
I couldn't believe my own eyes. This is precisely the formula I needed, and I had no idea it existed!
However, the Wikipedia page just claims its correctness, but doesn't add any citation.
If I have to use this formula in the proof of the paper, I really need to know where it comes from. I might as well just try to prove it on my own, but I am afraid that will not be a solution: the editors have given us a very strict page limit, and there is no way we'll be able to stay within that limit if we add this proof as well. Similarly, I can't use an unproven formula in a paper.
I really need to find a reference for this fact in a textbook or in a peer-reviewed article, and cite it in the paper.
I tried looking on the internet, but I couldn't find anything.
Has anyone seen this before? Is this a well-known fact I just missed?
Thanks in advance.

Now that we have the formula, it's probably very easy to prove it by induction.

With Approach Zero you can search formulas in math.stackexchange.com and artofproblemsolving.com.

Fabius' link uncovers the OEIS entry and with it several citations: https://oeis.org/A001142

Melanzio, now, you can cite your own question: @MISC {484413,
TITLE = {Product of all binomial coefficients},
AUTHOR = {Melanzio (https://mathoverflow.net/users/528900/melanzio)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {MathOverflow},
NOTE = {URL:https://mathoverflow.net/q/484413 (version: 2024-12-18)},
EPRINT = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/484413},
URL = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/484413}
}

There is an explicit form which is $$\prod _{j = 0}^N {}\binom{N}{j}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)^n}{G(n+1) G(n+2)}$$ where $G(.)$ is Barnes function. It is very convenient for calculation purposes.

This is A001142 in OEIS; but I am not sure whether the references given there are useful for you.
There is also a related post on [math.se]: Closed form for $\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$.

@usul Thank you! I took that into consideration, but unfortunately my advisor wasn't really okay with citing forum discussions! :(

The formula is rather trivial to deserve a reference. Factoring $\binom{N}j = \frac{1\cdot 2\cdots N}{(1\cdot 2\cdots j)\cdot(1\cdot 2\cdots (N-j))}$, we note that each $k\in [N]$ appears as a factor $N+1$ times in the numerator of the expansion (without cancelling) of $\prod_{j=0}^N \binom{N}j$, and $2(N-k+1)$ times in its denominator. Hence,
$$\prod_{j=0}^N \binom{N}j = \prod_{k=1}^N k^{N+1-2(N-k+1)} = \prod_{k=1}^N k^{2k-N-1}.$$

Does $k\in[N]$ means $k\in (1,2,3...N) $?

@An_Elephant: Yes.

Here "without cancelling" means "we don't do/apply any cancelling" and not "remaining after applying cancelation". Just in case.

Sorry , I was counting only in factorial instead of the $\prod$.

Several excellent questions have been proposed, but this is su concise that I will have to include it in the paper, especially because we can only write six pages.
Thanks!

I suggest you rewrite the identity as
$$
\prod_{j=0}^N \binom{N}{j} = \frac{(\prod_{k=1}^N k^k)^2}{(N!)^{N+1}},
$$
and this is the version I will use below.
Before starting the proof, the key point to be aware of is that binomial coefficients admit the identity
$$
\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}\binom{a-1}{b-1}
$$
when $a\geq b \geq 1$.
You can check the identity holds at $N=1$. (I checked it up to $N = 4$ to make sure it wasn’t mistyped.) Assuming it holds at a positive integer $N$, we have
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=0}^{N+1} \binom{N+1}{j} & = \prod_{j=1}^{N+1} \binom{N+1}{j} \\
& = \prod_{j=1}^{N+1} \frac{N+1}{j}\binom{N}{j-1}\\
& = \frac{(N+1)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}\prod_{j=0}^N\binom{N}{j}.
\end{align*}
By induction, that last product can be rewritten and we get
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=0}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{j} & = \frac{(N+1)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!} \frac{(\prod_{k=1}^N k^k)^2}{(N!)^{N+1}} \\
& = \frac{(N+1)^{2(N+1)}(\prod_{k=1}^N k^k)^2}{(N+1)^{N+1}(N+1)!(N!)^{N+1}}.
\end{align*}
The numerator is what we want and the denominator is $(N+1)!((N+1)!)^{N+1}$, which is $(N+1)!^{N+2}$ and that is also what we want. QED
As long as you keep in mind that $\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}\binom{a-1}{b-1}$, I would consider the argument above to be a straightforward induction: no special tricks are needed. It is the kind of thing a reader can be expected to derive on their own when the journal is tight on space. So if the journal you submit your paper to does not let you cite this MO page, just say in your paper that the identity can be proved by induction on $N$ while keeping in mind that $\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}\binom{a-1}{b-1}$ if $a\geq b \geq 1$.
Remark. There are few places in math where I have seen $k^k$ naturally show up (forget tetration, please). Besides the identity above, I can think of its role in Stirling’s estimate for $k!$ and in the Gauss—Legendre multiplication formula (distribution relation)
$$
G(z)G(z+1/k)\cdots G(z+(k-1)/k) = \sqrt{k}\frac{G(kz)}{k^{kz}},
$$
where $G(z) = \Gamma(z)/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Well, of course $n^n$ is the number of functions from a set of size $n$ to itself. For instance, Joyal's proof of Cayley's formula starts from this observation.

The van der Waerden conjecture (Egorychev-Falikman theorem) says that the permanent of a $k\times k$ doubly stochastic matrix is at least $k!/k^k$.

@TimothyChow is that lower bound known to be sharp in any sense, e.g., asymptotically close for infinitely many $k$?

Yes, it's sharp. Take the matrix whose entries are all equal to $1/k$.

The left side counts structures of the form a|a,b|a,b,c|,..., where the $k$th grouping consists of $k$ distinct elements from $\{1,\dots,N\}$.
Counting another way: we pick the first element of each grouping (the a's above), with $N^N$ choices; then the second element of those groupings with at least two elements, giving $(N-1)^{N-1}$ choices, and so on, for a total of $\prod_{k=1}^N k^k$.
But oops: on the left side, order within a grouping doesn't matter. So on the right, we'd better divide by $2$ for each grouping with at least two elements (we could swap those two), of which there are $N-1$. Then we must additionally divide by $3$ for each grouping with at least three elements (after optionally swapping the first two, we could insert the third element in three different places), and so on. So we'd better divide by $\prod_{k=1}^N k^{N-k+1}$.
We get $\prod_{k=1}^N k^{k - (N-k+1)} = \prod_{k=1}^N k^{2k-N-1}$.
...
As a side note, we could have more simply corrected the double counting with the perhaps-more-appealing denominator $\prod_{k=1}^N k!$, which would yield the aesthetic identity
$$ \prod_{k=1}^N {N \choose k} = \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{k^k}{k!} . $$
...
(Since this is MO, I'll hope it's generally on-topic when given an identity to post your favorite proof, even if that's not exactly the question.)

Nice. This is almost as succinct as Max's proof, if you delete the unnecessary "but oops" paragraph. Also, in your final rewriting of the identity, we can cancel the $k!$'s on both sides, and then Max's argument of comparing factors becomes even easier.

I'm not sure "as succinct as possible" is necessarily the goal here—I suppose that, if one wishes to reproduce this argument in a paper, then one can delete it there.  In the meantime, I enjoyed "but oops", as, if nothing else, a glimpse of how @‍usul presumably thought up this proof.

"Brevity is the soul of wit" - some guy somewhere. FWIW, I don't take Christian's comment as criticism, just a constructive point!

@usul: Exactly. I was just pointing out that the "but oops" paragraph is poetry and a more technical write-up of the argument would be about as short as Max's answer.
